# Navigating after logout with React/Redux

Tags: react-redux, logout

I'm trying to navigate back to my home page after the logout function is called, but the navigation is not working. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

relevant code from store/auth.js file:

```
export const logout = (navigate) => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_AUTH', auth: {} });
    navigate('/');
  };
};

export default auth;
```

App.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchProducts } from '../store/products';
import Home from './Home';
import Products from './Product/Products';
import Product from './Product/Product';
import Login from './Login/Login';
import User from './User/User';
import Cart from './Cart/Cart';
import Orders from './Cart/Orders';
import OrderSuccess from './Cart/OrderSuccess';

import { loginWithToken } from '../store';
import { logout } from '../store';
import { fetchCart } from '../store';
import OrderCancelled from './Cart/OrderCancelled';

import { CartElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const App = () => {
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
    dispatch(loginWithToken());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.id) {
      dispatch(fetchCart());
    }
  }, [auth]);


  return (
    <div>
      {!!auth.id ? (
        <div>
          <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-sm'>
            <Link className='navbar-brand link-dark mx-4' to='/'>Elysium</Link>
            <button 
              type='button' 
              data-bs-toggle='collapse' 
              data-bs-target='#navbarNav' 
              className='navbar-toggler mx-4'
              aria-controls='navbarNav'
              aria-expanded='false'
              aria-label='Toggle navigation'
            >
              <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
            </button>
            <div id='navbarNav' className="collapse navbar-collapse mx-4 justify-content-end">
              <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='/products'>Shop</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='/cart'>Cart</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to={`/user/${auth.id}`}>Account</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='#' onClick={() => dispatch(logout(navigate))}>Log Out</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<Product />} />
            <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
            <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />
            <Route path="/order-success" element={<OrderSuccess />} />
            <Route path='/order-cancelled' element={<OrderCancelled />} />
            <Route path="/user/:id" element={<User />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-sm'>
            <Link className='navbar-brand link-dark mx-4' to='/'>Elysium</Link>
            <button 
              type='button' 
              data-bs-toggle='collapse' 
              data-bs-target='#navbarNav' 
              className='navbar-toggler mx-4'
              aria-controls='navbarNav'
              aria-expanded='false'
              aria-label='Toggle navigation'
            >
              <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
            </button>
            <div id='navbarNav' className="collapse navbar-collapse mx-4 justify-content-end">
              <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='/products'>Shop</Link>
                </li>
                {/* <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='/#'>Cart</Link>
                </li> */}
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <Link className='link-dark mx-4' to='/login'>Log In</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<Product />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
};
```

export default App;

I was expecting this to navigate to the home page, but it stays on the same page after logout.